# LINQ to XML query attributes

Tags: xml, linq

using LINQ to XML, this is a sample of my XML

```
<shows>
 <Show Code="456" Name="My Event Name">
   <Event Code="2453" VenueCode="39" Date="2010-04-13 10:30:00" /> 
   <Event Code="2454" VenueCode="39" Date="2010-04-13 13:30:00" /> 
   <Event Code="2455" VenueCode="39" Date="2010-04-14 10:30:00"  /> 
   <Event Code="2456" VenueCode="39" Date="2010-04-14 13:30:00" /> 
   <Event Code="2457" VenueCode="39" Date="2010-04-15 10:30:00" /> 
 </Show>

 <Show... />
 <Show... />
</shows>
```

How do I return a list of the Dates for a specfic show? I am passing the show code ("456") in the querystring and want all the dates/times returned as a list.

This is the code i have so far:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("path to xml");

            var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Show")
                        where feed.Attribute("Code").Equals("456")
                        select new
                        {
                            EventDate = feed.Attribute("Date").Value
                        };

            foreach(var feed in feeds)
            {
                Response.Write(feed.EventDate + "<br />");
            }
```

But i get no results returned

Comment: @reinierpost: No, he's trying to iterate the child Event tags from Show="456". Value "2456" is an Event code. ;-)

Comment: @Prutswonder - you are correct!

Comment: @kb: As noted in my answer you're trying to find the Date attribute within Show, not within Event. It's possible that you need another "from" clause...

Comment: I thought the "Show" wouldn't be its own .Descendant, but what do I know ... I was just passing by.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The attribute isn't going to *equal* "456" - it's an attribute, not a string. However, if you convert it to a string first, it will work.

```
var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Show")
            where (string)feed.Attribute("Code") == "456"
            select new
            {
                EventDate = feed.Attribute("Date").Value
            };
```

An alternative would be to `int` to make sure it's numeric:

```
var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Show")
            where (int) feed.Attribute("Code") == 456
            select new
            {
                EventDate = feed.Attribute("Date").Value
            };
```

EDIT: Okay, I've now got this as a short but complete program to show it working.

Note that your original code will only work if the "Show" element has a "Date" attribute - which it doesn't in your sample XML. Note that it's trying to take the "Date" from the *"Show"* element not the *"Event"* element. I'm not sure what you really wanted to do here, so I've changed the code to just cast to `DateTime?` instead. The code below works and prints 1 (i.e. it's found the single Show element matching the code):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public static class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("shows.xml");
        var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Show")
                    where (int) feed.Attribute("Code") == 456
                    select new
                    {
                        EventDate = (DateTime?) feed.Attribute("Date")
                    };

        Console.WriteLine(feeds.Count());
    }
}
```

If you're *actually* trying to find every event date within the show, you need another "from" clause to make it iterate over the events within the show:

```
var events = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Show")
             where (int) feed.Attribute("Code") == 456
             // We can't use event as an identifier, unfortunately
             from ev in feed.Elements("Event")
             select new
             {
                 EventDate = (DateTime?) ev.Attribute("Date")
             };
```

Comment: ok, i've corrected my mistake, I am now evaluating the attributes' value, but I am still getting no results. 

As 'reinierpost' points out "No, he's trying to iterate the child Event tags from Show="456". Value "2456" is an Event code." This is correct. I want to return all dates for the show code '456'. So i need to iterate through the 'Event' elements

Comment: @kb: See my edit. It's not clear what you're really trying to do with the date, but the code *will* find the show...

Comment: Thanks Jon your post above has solved my problem! i was thinking that i may need to use an addition where clause to iterate through the Events Dates! thank you

Comment: nice tip to invert the equal. I like it. But it could just as well use the operator == and no trick would be needed, or am I missing smthg?

Comment: @serbrech: Nope, not missing anything at all. I'm silly :) Will edit.

Answer (score 6):

Change this line:

```
where feed.Attribute("Code").Equals("456")
```

To:

```
where feed.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("456")
```

Otherwise you're comparing the attribute as object instead of the attribute's value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
   var nodes = xmlFile.Nodes()
  .OfType<XElement>()
    .DescendantNodes()
  .OfType<XElement>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Event" && x.Attribute("Code").Value.Contains("456"));
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("Code"));
}
```