# LINQ to XML finding position in siblings list based on multiple attributes

Tags: linq-to-xml

Given the following structure. How would I get the position of the scene node with the id="3" among siblings, but only counting in siblings list with type="chapter" (which would be 1 in the provided example)?

```
<scene id="a">
      <scene id="b">
        <scene id="c" type="toc">
          <scene id="1" type="chapter"></scene>
          <scene id="2" type="other"></scene>
          <scene id="3" type="chapter"></scene> <!-- get the "sibling index" of this one, but based on id and type -->
          <scene id="4" type="chapter"></scene>
        </scene>
      </scene>
</scene>
```

EDIT:

My own solution was something like (sorry for not posting it):

```
var sceneC = from scene in rootElement.Descendants("scene") where (string)scene.Attribute("id") == "c" select scene;
var index = -1;
foreach (var scene in sceneC.Elements("scene"))
{
    if (scene.Attribute("type").Value.Equals("chapter"))
    {
         index++;
         if (scene.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("3"))
         {
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

But the provided solution seems much more elegant.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you have any code to show us? Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591096/linq-to-xml-query-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(
@"<scene id=""a"">
      <scene id=""b"">
        <scene id=""c"" type=""toc"">
          <scene id=""1"" type=""chapter""></scene>
          <scene id=""2"" type=""other""></scene>
          <scene id=""3"" type=""chapter""></scene>
          <scene id=""4"" type=""chapter""></scene>
        </scene>
      </scene>
</scene>");
XElement sceneC = rootElement.Element("scene").Element("scene");
int theIndex = sceneC.Elements().TakeWhile(n => n.Attribute("id").Value != "3")
                     .Count(x => x.Attribute("type").Value == "chapter");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you recommend any good resources for LINQ to XML? (just if some pop into mind)